Nginx 403/404 error when moving index to /home
I'm working on my Raspberry Pi and have setup there a nginx server for my first time. My laptop is in the same WiFi network,so I can access the server by entering the Raspberry's IP.
I want to have the index.html file in my home folder, but I'm struggling and would like to ask for your help.
This is so far what was attempted:

i've installed nginx regularly via apt install and i'm able to access the default page via the RaspberryPi IP

but when i copy index.nginx-debian.html into /home/pi-simon/html and change /etc/nginx/sites-available/default accordingly it doesn't work anymore, resulting in a 403 Forbidden:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # root /var/www/html;
        root /home/pi-simon/html;
        index index.html index.nginx-debian.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


depending on where I locate my index.nginx-debian.html (and default setting accordingly) the outcome is different:



location of index.nginx-debian.html
/var/www/html
/home
/home/pi-simon
/home/pi-simon/html




outcome for http://raspberrypi.local/
OK
OK
403 Forbidden
404 Not Found




these are my access permissions

i've changed the permissions to www-data but that did not help see here

changing the linetry_files $uri $uri/ =404; did only change the error output between 403 and 404

i've double-checked for spelling mistakes and restarted nginx after every change


Could my nginx.conf be wrong?
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

#   server {
#       listen 8080;
#       root /data/up1;
#
#       location / {
#       }
#   }
}

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

Thank you for your support! Let me know if you need more information.

i had to change permissions to 750 with sudo chmod 750 /home/pi-simon/anavi-phat-sensors-ui
now i can access index.nginx-debian.html via raspberry.local.
